# Why i can't access $post datas in my Wordpress single custom post type template?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm facing a really strange issue on my Wordpress plugin development :

I made a custom post type who's working perfectly.
I actually have to define my single.php template on the plugin to propose a ready public page.

I found the "single_template" filter who allow me to define my own template and override the default template for my custom post type.

It's actually working good and i can start the integration.

My problem is that i can't access the POST object/datas in this template, i didn't found a lot of similar cases on the web and would appreciate any help to fix this.

Here are some parts of my code :

**Filter to define my own template for the single page**

```
function get_teams_single_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $post->post_type == 'mt_teams' ) {
        $single_template = cdev_mt_directory . 'templates/teams/single-mt_teams.php';
    }

    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_teams_single_template' );
```

**The way i'm trying to get my post => $post return null**

```
<?php     
    include_once '../../../../../wp-load.php';
    get_header();
    global $post;
    var_dump($post);
    die();
```

If i try the wp function get_post(), it also return null..

Thanks a lot

Comment: A template does not have to include `wp-load.php`. Take a look at other template files.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Hi, i had to add this because without this call, i have the following fatal error :

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in ...

Comment: How do you access this template file? Any chances you are referencing it directly in the browser?

Comment: Not sure if i understood correctly your question i'm sorry.

If you mean how i access this page on the website, that's my custom post type single view.
If you mean in the code, that's the "templates/teams/single-mt_teams.php" file, included on the "single_template" filter.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by replacing my global variable which defined the plugin path.

I was using the **plugin_dir_url method** and had a url include error, so I replaced this method with **plugin_dir_path**, which resolved all my conflicts.